# Align individual Div at the bottom of bootstrap col 1

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

[image]

So I was trying make Related box stick at the bottom and aligns to the height of the next bootstrap div which is the business card section

The sort/filter divs should stay on top as they are sticky divs. They stick while scrolling.

The structure looks like this:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <div id="filter-panels">
      </div>

      <div id="related-services">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <div id="business-cards">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The `#related-services` div must be positioned at the bottom of the grid... and must be aligned to the last business card, and the `#filter-panels` div must stay at the top because it's a sticky div.

I tried by adding the following to both `.col-xs-12` divs...

```
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: bottom;
float: none
```

the `#related-services` div did stay at the bottom, but the `#filter-panels` div stayed at the bottom as well which is not what I expected...

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved using [**flexbox**](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

The trick is to give `display: flex` to **both** the container and the two columns. Then you can align the two components of the left-hand column by using `flex-direction: column` in conjunction with `justify-content: space-between`:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}

.left,
.right {
  display: flex;
  width: 50%;
}

.left {
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

#filter-panels,
#related-services {
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
}

#business-cards {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">
    <div id="filter-panels">Filter panels</div>
    <div id="related-services">Related services</div>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <div id="business-cards">Business cards</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps! :)